# Upload csv file with products. not working

Tags: magento-1.9, import, csv

i have a job of making a new shop for a client. He has an existing shop in another platform - Dandomain

The client has over 1000 products, so clearly i want to make an product import.

Dandomain have a export product to csv function, but magento wont accept the csv file.

How can i make magento accept it? :)

Comment: Can you share what the .csv file looks like

Comment: Yeah, but its quite big, so what in the file can help you? :D

Comment: I am talking about the header

Comment: PRODUCTS           
PROD_NUM LANGUAGE_ID PROD_NAME PROD_WEIGHT PROD_PHOTO_URL PROD_RETAIL_PRICE PROD_COST_PRICE CURRENCY_CODE UNIT_PRICE STOCK_COUNT DESC_SHORT DESC_LONG

This is the top

Answer (score 0):

Just try to install `Magmi` Magento Extention.
Very Fast and Easy.

[Here is the Magmi Plugin url](http://wiki.magmi.org)

Comment: Ive tried but, it does not seam to work :(

Comment: what is the format of CSV?

Comment: the header should be like this  name sku simples_skus configurable_attributes _store attribute_set type category _product_websites carmake carmodel color size weight price qty status    etc

Comment: So what should my header look like?